# Accessing private class variable Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a private void class which is my button and that button is getting some resutls from database, i need those variables to be used in another private class, how should i do it?
sorry if im wrong, im a newbie please help...

```
private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String search_updt= search_username_fld.getText();

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,dbname,dbpass);
        Statement log = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        //search for the user in database
        ResultSet rs_log = log.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='"+search_updt+"'");

        while(rs_log.next()){
            String rs_user = rs_log.getString("username");
            String rs_pass = rs_log.getString("password");
            String rs_first = rs_log.getString("first_name");
            String rs_last = rs_log.getString("last_name");

            //if authentication for user successful, go to user panel
            if(rs_user.equals(search_updt)){
                update.setVisible(false);
                updating.setVisible(true);
                this.setSize(430, 391);
             }

            //else show error
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username Not Found!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){  
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

i need to access rs_user,rs_pass,... from another private class

Comment: *Getters* and *setters* are your friends. Read about [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: "private void class" What are they?

Comment: You should follow this tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I think you are messing up class and method. You have here a private method, which by the way is not identical to your button. You have declared method level variables. Go instead with class level variables which you can access from all over your class.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider using `Observer` pattern because you have local variables that other classes need and your `ResutSet` consists of 0 or many records.

```
public class ResultSetEvent {
    private String rs_user;
    private String rs_pass;
    // ...

    public ResultSetEvent(String user, String pass) {
        this.rs_user = user;
        this.rs_pass = pass;
    }

    // getters / setters

}

public interface SearchActionResultListener {
    void handleResult(ResultSetEvent event);
} 

public class MyClass {
    private List<SearchActionResultListener> listeners = new LinkedList<SearchActionResultListener>();
    public void addSearchActionResultListener(SearchActionResultListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    public void removeSearchActionResultListener(SearchActionResultListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
    //...

    private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //...
        while(rs_log.next()){
            String rs_user = rs_log.getString("username");
            String rs_pass = rs_log.getString("password");
            //...

            ResultSetEvent event = new ResultSetEvent(rs_user, rs_pass)
            for(SearchActionResultListener l : this.listeners) {
                l.handleResult(event);
            }
        }
        //...
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass implements SearchActionResultListener {
    private MyClass reference;

    public MyOtherClass() {
        // reference = ...
        reference.addSearchActionResultListener(this);  
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultSetEvent event) {
        // handle the event
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@user3315606: Your class structuring is not proper but it is acceptable because you have mentioned that you a new guy for java dev.
I give you the detail on this:

Fist of all if you want to access any variable of a class into another class then they should come at the class level with private access specifiers and they should have public getters and setters associated.

Below is the Dummy class according to your requirement :

```
public class Dummy{

  private String rs_user;
  private String rs_pass;
  private String rs_first;
  private String rs_last;

  public void setRs_user(String rs_user){
    this.rs_user = rs_user;
  }

  public void setRs_pass(String rs_pass){
    this.rs_pass = rs_pass;
  }

  public void setRs_first(String rs_first){
    this.rs_first = rs_first;
  }

  public void setRs_last(String rs_last){
    this.rs_last = rs_last;
  }

  public String getRs_user{
    return rs_user;
  }

  public String getRs_pass{
    return rs_pass;
  }

  public String getRs_first{
    return rs_first;
  }

  public String getRs_last{
    return rs_last;
  }

  private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
     ...
     setRs_user(rs_log.getString("username"));
     setRs_pass(rs_log.getString("password"));
     setRs_first(rs_log.getString("first_name"));
     setRs_last(rs_log.getString("last_name"));
     ...
  }
  ...
}

Now if you want to access rs_user, rs_pass ... in other classes then you can use getters method for these properties.
Like fot rs_user you can use getRs_user() method on the object of Dummy class.
```